# Rolling back previously committed transaction

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, transactions

In the service I am currently developing I need to provide a twofold operation:

1. The request being made should be registered in the database (using `Register()` method); and
2. The request should be sent to an external *webservice* for further processing (using `Dispatch()` method).

Considering that I can't switch the order of the operations, I would like to be able to "rollback" the first one if something goes wrong with the second, so that a then-invalid record does not get inserted to the BD. The problem here is that, of course, I am commiting the transaction inside the `Register` method. Is there any way I can roll it back from inside the `Dispatch` method if anything goes wrong?

Edit: All transaction are being managed from the .NET-side.

Comment: You need a [two-phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol). This is basically what the [MSDTC](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc759136%28WS.10%29.aspx) does, and that is your best bet: Use the distributed transaction cordinator. But I think it is better to rethink your complete transaction strategy. Try to design the system in such way that you don't need distributed atomicy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database won't help you in this case.  You have to create compensating transactions, using pairs of operations that undo each other.  Your services will effectively have to replace all the work and logic that has gone into relational databases for managing transactions.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention, however, that all transactions are being managed from the .NET-side.

Comment: Doesn't change my answer - you'll have to do all of it.